# Как отменить действие click

Tags: html, javascript

Я хотел сделать навигацию без перезагрузки страницы.

С использованием jQuery я присвоил обработчик всем a-элементам, в обработчике написал **e.preventDefault()**, чтобы не переходило на другую страницу, а аргумент **href** обрабатываю в функции, но работает только через раз.

Помогите пожалуйста, я не знаю как сделать, чтобы не переходило на другую страницу. Код:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').bind("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(href);
        $.post(
            href,
            {},
            function(data){
                history.pushState(null, null, href);
                data = data.substring(37, data.length-14);
                data = data.split("</head><body>");
                $('title').html('Title');
                document.body.innerHTML=data[1];
            }
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: в обработчик функций *а*, в конце 
не забыли написать *return false*?

Comment: дописал, но всё равно не работает как нужно

Comment: надо взглянуть на код. По описанию вы всё правильно делаете.

Comment: ммм..тогда уберите preventDefault, оставьте return false;

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: @TAPAHbl4, "`return false;`" вынесите из "`$.post()`" и поставьте после =)

Comment: В функции вроде ошибок нет
Какие именно таймауты?
bind("click", function(e){}) аргумент вынес
return true нету
$.off таким не пользуюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@TAPAHbl4](/users/10237/tapahbl4)](/users/10237/tapahbl4), я это до кода отправил. Выношу в ответ, ибо не влезает. Должно работать так:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "a", function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(href);
    $.post(href, {}, function(data){
      history.pushState(null, null, href);
      data = data.substring(37, data.length-14);
      data = data.split("</head><body>");
      $('title').html('Title');
      document.body.innerHTML=data[1];
    });
    return false; 
  });
});
```

еще я бы вам посоветовал отправлять в post "ajax=1", а в php в зависимости от `$_POST['ajax']` выводить либо весь сайт, либо только нужный контент.

**UPD** Обновил, сделал `live`, ибо у вас после обновления html новые ссылки работали "как обычно". Видимо, потому и "через раз" ))

Comment: Не работает. Теперь сайт ярко выражено "моргает" и в левом верхнем углу надпись undefined

Comment: обновил ответ)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: @TAPAHbl4 для jquery < 1.7 

    $(document).on("click", "a", ...);
    // заменить на 
    $("a").live("click", ...);

Comment: @Spectre, false, можно. У автора jq старая

[Пруф](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

    Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all three event attachment methods:

    $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
    $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
    $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Спасибо, работает :)